# Android access denied finding property "ro.hardware.chipname"

Tags: android, kotlin, tensorflow-lite

So I am trying to use Tensorflow Lite on an android app. The following code is called when the camera captures an image:

```kotlin
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        val bitmap = data!!.extras!!.get("data") as Bitmap
        val tensorImage = imageProcessor.process(TensorImage(DataType.UINT8).apply { load(bitmap) })
        val outputs = model.process(tensorImage.tensorBuffer)
        val buffer = outputs.outputFeature0AsTensorBuffer
        val prediction = buffer.floatArray
        debug { "$prediction" }
    }
}
```

However, after executing the line `val outputs = model.process(tensorImage.tensorBuffer)`, an error message

`E/libc: Access denied finding property "ro.hardware.chipname"`

popped up. I have no clue about the meaning of the message (even after googling), and I seemingly cannot find a suitable permission to allow this. Any help in advance is much appreciated.

Comment: I have discovered that this the program did not crash due to this message but I still find this extremely frustrating as there are no concrete information about this on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

I did encounter the same problem in my flutter/dart project, when I was trying to use NNAPI on XiaoMi Redmi K30 Pro(Snapdragon 865). Until now, there's still no concrete information about this.
Few pages i found which may have sth to do with it:

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/7887

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/45847

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).